# How to use jquery TableSorter with a fieldset?

Tags: apex, jquery, tablesorter

I can successfully use the jquery tablesorter in a  dataTable with columns explicity enumerated:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!displayedAttendances}" var="att" styleClass="tablesorter" id="attendees">
                <apex:column headerValue="First Name" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!att.attendance.first_name__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!att.attendance.last_name__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!att.attendance.status__c}" />
                </apex:column>
```

However, if I use a field set, the columns collapse right on top of each other after a field update in the table (e.g., update the field Status and the columns collapse):

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!displayedAttendances}" var="att" styleClass="tablesorter" id="attendees">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.SC_Attendance__c.FieldSets[fieldSet]}" var="field">
          <apex:column headerValue="{!field.label}">
                 <apex:inputField value="{!att.attendance[field]}" >
                       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!att.changeRecord}" rerender="attend" />
                  </apex:inputField>
          </apex:column>
       </apex:repeat>
<apex:dataTable />
```

Can someone help me get this to work with a fieldset?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include some code, it is really hard to help in the abstract.

Comment: Corrected the code display.

Comment: Your markup does not include the element that is actually being rerendered. Nor does it contain the javascript you are using to implement tablesorter. The issue may revolve around one/both of those.

Comment: Resolved:  I had to rerender the block with the tablesorter javascript after an update.

Comment: Ha figured as much.